# Exclude specific tensors being updated by optimizer in TensorFlow

Tags: graph, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I have two graphs, which I suppose to train them independently, which means I have two different optimizers, but at the same time one of them is using the tensor values of the other graph. As a result, I need to be able to stop specific tensors being updated while training one of the graphs. I have assigned two different namescopes two my tensors and using this code to control updates over tensors for different optimizers:

```
mentor_training_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, "mentor")
train_op_mentor = mnist.training(loss_mentor, FLAGS.learning_rate, mentor_training_vars)
mentee_training_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, "mentee")
train_op_mentee = mnist.training(loss_mentee, FLAGS.learning_rate, mentee_training_vars)
```

the vars variable is being used like below, in the training method of mnist object:

```
def training(loss, learning_rate, var_list):

  # Add a scalar summary for the snapshot loss.
  tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
  # Create the gradient descent optimizer with the given learning rate.
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
  # Create a variable to track the global step.
  global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
  # Use the optimizer to apply the gradients that minimize the loss
  # (and also increment the global step counter) as a single training step.
  train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step, var_list=var_list)
  return train_op
```

I'm using the **var_list** attribute of the **optimizer class** in order to control vars being updated by the optimizer.

Right now I'm confused whether I have done what I supposed to do appropriately, and even if there is anyway to check if any optimizer would only update partial of a graph?

I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure there's an easy way, but you could record the value after some iterations and check if it changed.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem and used the same approach as you, i.e. via the `var_list` argument of the optimizer. I then checked whether the variables not intended for training stayed the same using:

```
the_var_np = sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('the_var:0'))
assert np.equal(the_var_np, pretrained_weights['the_var']).all()
```

`pretrained_weights` is a dictionary returned by `np.load('some_file.npz')` which I used to store the pre-trained weights to disk.

Just in case you need that as well, here is how you can override a tensor with a given value:

```
value = pretrained_weights['the_var']
variable = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('the_var:0')
sess.run(tf.assign(variable, value))
```